Understanding almost quasi-simple groups
By the definition from here, a group $G$ is termed an almost quasi-simple group if it has a quasi-simple normal subgroup $H$ such that $C_G(H)\leq H$ (equivalently, the induced homomorphism $G/Z(H) \to\operatorname{Aut}(H)$, via the action by conjugation, is injective.) Recall that, by $H$ is quasi-simple, we mean that $H$ is perfect and $H/Z(H)$ is a simple group, say $S$.
Am I right that the induced homomorphism $G/H\to\operatorname{Out}(H)$ is also injective? Is it true that $Z(G)=Z(H)$? Is it true that $G/Z(G)$ is an almost simple group?
Thanks in advanced, and I am sorry if my questions are either nonsense or trivial.

In order to answer this we work through the definitions a bit.

The subgroup $H$ is quasisimple. If $C_G(H)\leq H$ then in particular $C_G(H)\leq C_H(H)=Z(H)$, so $C_G(H)=Z(H)$. On the other hand, why should an automorphism of $G$ centralize $Z(H)$? It will if $|Z(H)|\leq 2$, but think if $|Z(H)|=3$ and $H$ has an automorphism of order $2$ that inverts the centre. There are lots of examples of such things. Think of $H$ as being a group $SL_n(q)$ where the centre does not have order $1$ or $2$. The inverse-transpose automorphism inverts the centre.

We see from the example of $SL$ with a 2 on top above that $Z(G)$ can be strictly smaller than $Z(H)$, in which case we certainly cannot have that $G/Z(G)$ is almost simple. We claim that $G/Z(H)$ is always almost simple. This is not immediately obvious: why is $C_G(H/Z(H))=Z(H)$? Can you not have an automorphism $\phi$ of $H$ that acts trivially on $H/Z(H)$, i.e., $[H,\phi]\leq Z(H)$ but is non-trivial? The answer is no. The short way is as follows: $H$ is a normal, quasisimple subgroup of $G$. Thus it is a component of $G$, and if I take any subnormal subgroup $X$ of $G$, either $H$ is a component of $X$ or $[H,X]=1$. (See, for example, Aschbacher's book, (31.4).) If $X=C_G(H/Z(H))$, which is a normal subgroup of $G$, we obtain the result.



So what about the statement that $G/H\to Out(H)$ being injective? Suppose there exists $x,y\in G$ and $h$ in $H$ such that $xy^{-1}h\in Z(H)$ (i.e., $xy^{-1}$ induces an inner automorphism on $H$, so $x$ and $y$ induce the same element of $Out(H)$). Then $xy^{-1}h\in H$, so $xy^{-1}\in H$. Thus $Hx=Hy$, and so the map $G/H\to Out(H)$ is injective.

